# SQL Server 2012 if one of the columns contain 1 function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to figure how I could do this where I have a table as follows:

```
    ID  FKeyID          Complete
    1   6               1     
    2   6               0       
    3   6               0
    4   7               0
    5   8               0
    6   8               0
```

I want to create a function to return 1 or true if any FKeyID  for example 6 has a value of 1 in complete column and 0 if it does not.

This is a function that takes fKey value and should return 1 or 0 based on that.

So in above basically if my FKeyID is 6 return 1 because complete column is 1 in one of the rows, and 0 for FKeyID 8 because none of values in column complete is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE function [dbo].f_x
(
  @FKeyID int
) 
RETURNS bit
as
begin
return case when exists 
 (select 1 from test where Complete = 1 and FKeyID = @FKeyID) 
   then 1 else 0 end
end
```